¿El equipo "está" o "el equipo estamos"?
Un compañero de trabajo estaba respondiendo un correo electrónico y preguntó si era correcto poner:
"El equipo de (nombre de la empresa) estamos a su servicio"
No me sonó correcto y respondí que debía ser:
"El equipo de (nombre de la empresa) está a su servicio"
Pero una compañera dijo que ambas expresiones son correctas.
No estoy segura de ello.

Obviamente es correcto decir:

El equipo de (X empresa) está a su servicio (concordancia entre el sujeto y el verbo en 3ra persona del singular)

No obstante, "nosotros" puede recibir un sustantivo singular como atributo en el predicado:

Somos un gran equipo.

"El equipo de (X empresa) estamos a su servicio" no parece a primera vista una oración gramatical, salvo que el hablante forme parte del equipo:

Mis compañeros y yo somos el equipo (de X empresa).

La oración cuestionada sería una forma abreviada de:

Nosotros, el equipo (de X empresa), estamos a su servicio.

No obstante, la aposición "el equipo..." requiere el núcleo "nosotros" para concordar en plural. En este sitio podemos leer que el plural se considera incorrecto si "equipo" es el núcleo del sujeto.
Si el hablante desea involucrarse en el equipo, podría decir:

En el equipo (de X empresa) estamos a su servicio.

Todos los miembros del equipo (de X empresa) estamos a su servicio.



Las obras de referencia difieren sobre la aceptabilidad de una forma personal plural en el caso de una palabra indicativa de grupo o de cantidad. Para la mayoría de estas palabras -especialmente en el lenguaje escrito- es aconsejable elegir una forma de persona singular.
La palabra “equipo” es un sustantivo colectivo. Un sustantivo colectivo se refiere a un grupo de individuos o elementos considerados como una unidad.
Los sustantivos colectivos tienen algunas características que los distinguen de otros tipos de sustantivos:
•   Representan un grupo o conjunto de elementos.
•   Son singulares, aunque se refieran a un conjunto de cosas.
Ejemplo: La multitud de personas esperaba afuera del estadio.
El complemento nominal especifica o aclara el significado del sustantivo al que acompaña, en este caso, «multitud». El sustantivo se considera el núcleo y usualmente el verbo permanece en singular, incluso cuando este complemento está en plural.
